# open file of python 3.2 IDLE after saving it

Tags: python-3.x

I had download python - Windows X86-64 MSI Installer (3.2.5), but after working on  IDLE and saving the file on my desktop, I can't open it- instead  there is message:"Choose the program you want to use to open this file". why? what can I do? there wasn't such a problem when I had Python 3.3   [image]

Comment: Can't you just tell Windows to use IDLE?

Comment: No, when I click right there isn't such an option...

Comment: I'm not on a Windows PC right now, but there has to be such an option. Either in the file's properties, or in the file explorer's settings. Take a look [here](http://notebooks.com/2011/02/08/how-to-set-default-programs-and-use-open-with-and-always-open-with-settings/).

Comment: @  tobias_k I  edited the message with what it look like

Comment: So it tells you to choose a program... and what happens then? Is IDLE not in the list, or does it forget what you selected the next time you open it? What about the other approaches from the link?

Comment: IDLE is not in the list and when i try to send the file using e-mail it doesn't download it as one of python file's  ___.py